# Jquery slot machine get index result and change background

Tags: jquery

i have this code from [josex2r](http://www.danielmagliola.com/demos/slots/) Jquery Slot Machine

this code shows whats currently active by showing what number of that active slot is (the js code)

```
<div id="machine1" class="slotMachine">
<div class="slot slot1"></div>
<div class="slot slot2"></div>
<div class="slot slot3"></div>
<div class="slot slot4"></div>
<div class="slot slot5"></div>
<div class="slot slot6"></div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
<div id="machine1Result" class="slotMachine noBorder" style="text-align:left">Index: 0</div>
<div id="machine2Result" class="slotMachine noBorder" style="text-align:left">Index: 1</div>
<div id="machine3Result" class="slotMachine noBorder" style="text-align:left">Index: 2</div>
<div class="slotMachine noBorder"></div>
</div>

function onComplete($el, active){
        switch($el[0].id){
                case 'machine1':
                    $("#machine1Result").text("Index: "+active.index);
                    break;
                case 'machine2':
                    $("#machine2Result").text("Index: "+active.index);
                    break;
                case 'machine3':
                    $("#machine3Result").text("Index: "+active.index);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The goal is ... once the user got the same result say "777" then change the background of some div.
achieving same goal from here: [Link](http://www.danielmagliola.com/demos/slots/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String together the 3 results and `if == 777` use `css()` to change background

```
function onComplete($el, active){

    var m1Index;
    var m2Index;
    var m3Index;

    switch($el[0].id) {
        case 'machine1':
            m1Index = active.index;
            $("#machine1Result").text("Index: "+ m1Index );                    
            break;
        case 'machine2':
            m2Index = active.index;
            $("#machine2Result").text("Index: " + m2Index );
            break;
        case 'machine3':
            m3Index = active.index;
            $("#machine3Result").text("Index: "+ m3Index  );
            break;
    }

     if (m1Index & m2Index & m3Index) {         

        if ("" + m1Index + m2Index + m3Index == "777") { 
            $('.someDiv').css({"backgroundColor": "green"});
        }

     }

}
```

First check that all three index exist and then check if combination of strings equal 777

Adding `""` to `if ("" +` forces the three numbers to a string